# How to write this as 1 line return Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop

My professor notes that this code can be condensed to one line of body. I'm not sure how to, even though I get a skeleton of it in my mind.

```
def dict_as_str(d : {None:None}, key : callable=None, reverse : bool=False) -> str:
    tempStr = ''
    for key in sorted(d.keys(), key=key, reverse = reverse):
        tempStr += "  " + str(key) +" -> " + str(d[key]) + "\n"
    return tempStr
```

Comment: Use a list comprehension. http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: Maybe `return '\n'.join(generator expression)`? That's the most obvious way I think.

Comment: @John1024: It’s an argument called `key` with a `callable` [type hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a generator expression will do it:

```
return "".join("  {} -> {}\n".format(key, d[key])
               for key in sorted(d, key=key, reverse=reverse))
```

Comment: You don't need to call `d.keys()`; `sorted(d, key=key, reverse=reverse)` will automatically get the keys when it calls `d.__iter__` to get an iterator.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for .Thank you!